# Removing strings with duplicate letters from string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq

I have array of strings like

```
string[] A = { "abc", "cccc", "fgaeg", "def" };
```

I would like to obtain a list or array of strings where any letter appears only one time. I means that "cccc", "fgaeg" will be removed from input array.
I managed to do this but I feel that my way is very messy, unnecessarily complicated and not efficient.

Do you have any ideas to improve this algorythm (possibliy replacing with only one Linq query)?

My code:

```
        var goodStrings = new List<string>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var str in A)
        {
            var tempArr = str.GroupBy(x => x)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Cnt = x.Count(),
                    Str = x.Key
                }).ToArray();

            var resultArr = tempArr.Where(g => g.Cnt > 1).Select(f => f.Str).ToArray();
            if(resultArr.Length==0) goodStrings.Add(A[i]);
            
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: I think, the check could be done with Regex, something like ".*(\w).*\1.*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Distinct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Distinct__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) method for every array item and get items with count of distinct items equals to original string length

```cs
string[] A = { "abc", "cccc", "fgaeg", "def" };
var result = A.Where(a => a.Distinct().Count() == a.Length).ToList();
```

You'll get list with `abc` and `def` values, as expected

Comment: Very nice approach. It didn't cross my mind. Simple and clean.

Comment: Also if strings can be long enough it might be worth it to get rid of all string with more than 26 character right of the bat.

Comment: @Franck Thank you, that's the good point. However, OP didn't mentioned such requirements, like string length or used alphabet